# Difficulty trying to export query results as a CSV, uploaded to SharePoint (PySpark)

Tags: python, pyspark, sharepoint, databricks

I am trying to run a query, with the result saved as a CSV that is uploaded to a SharePoint folder. This is within Databricks via Pyspark.

My code below is close to doing this, but the final line is not functioning correctly - the file generated in SharePoint does not contain any data, though the dataframe does.

I'm new to Python and Databricks, if anyone can provide some guidance on how to correct that final line I'd really appreciate it!

```
from shareplum import Site
from shareplum.site import Version
import pandas as pd

sharepointUsername = 
sharepointPassword = 

sharepointSite = 
website = 
sharepointFolder = 

# Connect to SharePoint Folder
authcookie = Office365(website, username=sharepointUsername, password=sharepointPassword).GetCookies()
site = Site(sharepointSite, version=Version.v2016, authcookie=authcookie)
folder = site.Folder(sharepointFolder)

FileName = "Data_Export.csv"

Query = "SELECT * FROM TABLE"

df = spark.sql(Query)
pandasdf = df.toPandas()

folder.upload_file(pandasdf.to_csv(FileName, encoding = 'utf-8'), FileName)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure my code is still garbage, but it does work. I needed to convert the dataframe into a variable containing CSV formatted data prior to uploading it to SharePoint; effectively I was trying to skip a step before. Last two lines were updated:

```
from shareplum.site import Version
import pandas as pd

sharepointUsername = 
sharepointPassword = 

sharepointSite = 
website = 
sharepointFolder = 

# Connect to SharePoint Folder
authcookie = Office365(website, username=sharepointUsername, password=sharepointPassword).GetCookies()
site = Site(sharepointSite, version=Version.v2016, authcookie=authcookie)
folder = site.Folder(sharepointFolder)

FileName = "Data_Export.csv"

Query = "SELECT * FROM TABLE"

df = (spark.sql(QueryAllocation)).toPandas().to_csv(header=True, index=False, encoding='utf-8')

folder.upload_file(df, FileName)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).